# QDialog:Trouble Loading Data Into QTableWidget From A User Input

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qdialog

I'm attempting to have a QDialog that gives the user the feature to search up data based on their input. The data is connected to a database.

The user types what they want to look for {self.search_name.text()} which is then queried in the database {self.c.execute} and displayed in a QTableWidget {package_list} after clicking search (self.loaddata).

The issue I am having is loading the data into the table. I know the query works because if I predefine what I want to look for in my code the table will populate. I am getting no errors when running the script.

Any ideas on how to fix this or maybe another way of accomplishing the same goal without using a QDialog?

```
 class SearchPackageByNameDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(SearchPackageByNameDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(28, 66, 32);\n"
"font: 10pt \"Courier New\";\n"
"")


        loadUi('GUIs/PackageLookupNameDailog.ui',self)

        self.btn_search.clicked.connect(self.loaddata)


        self.loaddata()


    def loaddata(self):

        searchrol = self.search_name.text()

        searchresult = '"'+searchrol+'"'


        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Packages(Tracking_Number TEXT PRIMARY KEY,Recipient TEXT,DateIn TEXT,DateOut TEXT)")
        self.c.close()


        self.package_list = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)

        self.package_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 600, 300))
        self.package_list.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.package_list.setColumnCount(4)
        self.package_list.setColumnWidth(0,200)
        self.package_list.setColumnWidth(1,200)
        self.package_list.setColumnWidth(2,100)
        self.package_list.setColumnWidth(3,100)
        self.package_list.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.package_list.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.package_list.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.package_list.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.package_list.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.package_list.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.package_list.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Tracking Number", "Recipient", "Date In", "Date Out"))
        self.package_list.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt 'Courier New';background-color: rgb(114, 104, 112);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(124, 136, 126);\n"
"border-color: rgb(160, 141, 131);\n"
"gridline-color: rgb(145, 150, 127);")


        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        query = "SELECT * from Packages WHERE recipient IS "+str(searchresult)
        result = self.connection.execute(query)
        print(query)
        self.package_list.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.package_list.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.package_list.setItem(row_number, column_number,QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        self.connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a *new* table each time `loaddata` is called.

If the table already exists in the ui you're using, then just use that, but from the look of your code it probably doesn't.

### How to solve it (in the *wrong* way)

For the sake of completeness, I'll tell you that you *could* just add the following line after creating the table:

```
    self.package_list.show()
```

This is required because when a widget is added to a parent and that widget is not managed by a layout (more about this later), that widget does **not** become visible if the parent already is.

The first time the dialog is created, it creates the table because you called `loaddata` in the `__init__`, and *then* the dialog is shown. In this case, when a parent is shown, each of its children are shown too (even if they were not explicitly shown) *unless* `hide()` or `setVisible(False)` is explicitly called on those widget. After that, any new "free" widget created as child *must* be explicitly shown with `show()` or `setVisible(True)`.

### BUT, no.

This should not be necessary. First of all, because if a table already exists, there's no need to create one.

The *correct* solution is to create the table in the `__init__`, possibly by setting *there* everything that will certainly not change by the search query: headers settings, alternating row colors, etc.

### Layouts, layouts, layouts

There are very, *very* few, rare and specific cases for which is absolutely necessary to use fixed geometries (`setGeometry()`, `move()`, `resize()`) for widgets. The rule of thumb is: if you're using fixed geometries, you're probably doing it wrong.

These are the main reasons for which it should be avoided:

- if the user resizes the window to a smaller size, some widgets will become partially or completely invisible: consider what happens for a user that has a smaller screen size than yours;
- if the window is resized to a *bigger* size, there will be a lot of unused space (and it will look ugly);
- what you see on your screen is almost **never** what others will see in theirs: different default font or DPI will potentially force some widgets to increase their minimum size, with the result that some widgets will overlap with others;

[Layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) are *always* the first and right choice, and you can easily create them within [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Do consider that this is mandatory even if you want to set a fixed size for your window (see the third point of the list above).

Comment: I'll be honest, I did the easy way just to make sure I can get it to work. But I am now looking over best practices regarding Layouts. I do want the ability for the user to full screen the app.

Comment: @Matt the fact that the app is shown in full screen or not is uninfluential: the point is that the UI *must* be able to adapt its contents according to the available size (it doesn't matter if that space is set by the user or the system). Be aware, layouts are not always your friends: sometimes compromises are required; but they *are* the better choice, as the alternative is almost always a *bad* one (both from the user and the programmer perspective).

Comment: The issue I'm having is what level of compromise I'm willing to deal with. I'm still learning how to have a layout but keep the same dimension of labels and buttons that I currently have. I'm sure there is a way but I just have to continue my research. This is my first time creating a GUI.

Comment: @Matt you can set a widget maximum and/or minimum size if you want (setting both maximum and minimum makes the size fixed) and still use layouts: in that way you have more control on the widget sizes, but you can also be sure that your UI will be *always* well layed out on any screen (that has a reasonable) size. I suggest you to read the documentation (the two link at the end of my question) and start doing some experiments in designer, so that you can better understand how they actually work. Have fun :-)